# sql server-how min and max blank the other row if they same result

Tags: sql-server

I want the join EmpID to EmployeeNo and combine the last name, first name, and middle name from the second table and I want to the entries separate the O and I with min and max but if they don't have a min or max become blank or null I just want to become blank the certain row because if they don't blank the row the result is the same.

### -----------------------------------------------------

this is the 1st

|Entries ............................... | recordDate            ............................. .|..Empid  ..........| Reference |
|..0016930507201907:35I....|..2019-05-07 00:00:00.000    ....... |..001693 .........|..1693|
|..0016930507201917:06O .|..2019-05-07 00:00:00.000     ........|..001693   .........|..1693|
|..0016930507201907:35I.. .|..2019-05-08 00:00:00.000    ....... |..001693 .........| ..1693|
                      ......................................... ...|..2019-05-08 00:00:00.000 .......   | ..001693  ........|..1693|

### ----------------------------------------------------

---

## 2nd table

.....|LastName|.........................|FirstName| ......... ...........|middleName| .......................|EmployeeNO|
.....|Cruz|..................................|Kimberly|...........................|Castillo|  ................................| 001693|

---

i want to join that two table with the second table combine the lastname,FirstName, and middleName . the employeeNo join to Empid but the entries would be separate between I and O with min or max of certain empId but if the entries have not I or O it would be blank like this and also with where

---

|name.....................................|EmployeeNO |............RecordDate      ............|...TimeIn...........|TimeOut|
|CRUZ, MA. KIMBERLY, CA....|001693...........|2019-05-07 00:00:00.000   ..|...07:35..............|05:06|
|CRUZ, MA. KIMBERLY,CA....|001693...........|2019-05-08 00:00:00.000...|...07:35      |

---

Comment: You need to explain this more. It might be easier to come up with a simple example of what you want and show that, than use the actual use case.  What are O and I? How can they not have a min or a max? I'm fairly sure you want a `CASE` statement so maybe start looking into that.

Comment: Welcome Kimberly. The way to get a quick answer here is to set the problem out really simply. To do that, you should paste everything that we would need to quickly reproduce your data into your question as create tables (table variables will do), insert statements, and your expected results. If you have tried some sql show that as well. Posting images is not a good way because it makes it very hard to follow, and anyone who would help then has to type all the data in themselves. Help us to help you.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenient i try my best to explain may i request to look it again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
SELECT CONCAT(t2.[LastName], ', ', t2.[FirstName], ', ', t2.[MiddleName]) AS [Name],
    t2.[EmployeeNO], t1.[RecordDate], 
    MIN(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('I', t1.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0, SUBSTRING(t1.[Entries], LEN(t1.[Entries]) - 5, 6), NULL)) AS [TimeIn],
    MAX(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('O', t1.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0, SUBSTRING(t1.[Entries], LEN(t1.[Entries]) - 5, 6), NULL)) AS [TimeOut]
    FROM [dbo].[Table_2] t2
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Table_1] t1 ON t2.[EmployeeNO] = t1.[Empid]
    GROUP BY CONCAT(t2.[LastName], ', ', t2.[FirstName], ', ', t2.[MiddleName]),
    t2.[EmployeeNO], t1.[recordDate]
```

*Note: as per your question

--[Table_1] is 1st table

--[Table_2] is 2nd table

Comment: What is the type of entries column? which version mssql you are using?

Comment: Entries column data type?

Comment: Had tried by keeping entries as nvarchar, it works. Post the data which is not working.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH !, may i know how to contact you if i have a question in my project or something about my working system?

Comment: sir i have question how to turn the time in and time out 12 hours not 24 hours

Comment: you can convert like this select CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST('17:06' AS TIME), 100)

Comment: for above query, CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), MIN(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('I', t1.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0, SUBSTRING(t1.[Entries], LEN(t1.[Entries]) - 5, 5), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeIn],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), MAX(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('O', t1.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0, CAST(SUBSTRING(t1.[Entries], LEN(t1.[Entries]) - 5, 5) AS TIME), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeOut]

Comment: you have concat if you want I & O at the end

Comment: i have error please help me" Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: "Select B.LastName + ',' + B.FirstName + ',' + B.MiddleName[Name] ,A.RecordDate,B.[EmployeeNO]
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, MIN(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('I', A.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0,CAST( SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5) AS TIME), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeIn], 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('O', A.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0, CAST(SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5) AS TIME), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeOut]   
FROM Employees  [B]
inner JOIN [DTR Upload] [A] ON B.EmployeeNo = A.EmpID

Comment: this is the extention
GROUP by B.LastName, B.FirstName, B.MiddleName,
 B.[EmployeeNO], A.[recordDate]--, C.Section
 order by A.[recordDate] asc, B.LastName + ','+B.FirstName + ','+ B.MiddleName asc" this is my full code please help me

Comment: that's happening if i remove the where please help me

Comment: Muthu R please help me i will waiting your answer

Comment: can you pls ping me in skype: muthuspeaks?

Comment: in email will do?

Comment: the code that you gave me how to remove column if the min and max is null